# How to show that the cokernel of $\mathbb{Z}[x]^2\to\mathbb{Z}[x]^2$ given by $A=\begin{pmatrix}2 & x \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ isn't a sum of cyclics?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, modules

Is it true that the cokernel of the map $\mathbb{Z}[x]^2\to\mathbb{Z}[x]^2$ given by the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}2 & x \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ cannot be written as a direct sum of cyclic modules?

I can show that $A$ isn't equivalent to a diagonal matrix up to multiplying by invertible matrices from the left and right. So what I would like to do is to deduce from an isomorphism to a direct sum of cyclic modules that this gives an equivalence of $A$ to a diagonal matrix. However, this always requires some sort of lifting which I'm not sure can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]$. The module you consider is canonically isomorphic to $M=R/(2,x)\times R$. If $M$ is isomorphic to a finite product of cyclic modules, they have isomorphic torsion part, and it boils down to decide whether $R/(2,x)$ is isomorphic to a sum of (torsion) cyclic modules.

If $R/(2,x)\simeq R/a_1R\times\cdots\times  R/a_rR$ for some non zero $a_i$, then they have the same annihilators. Now $P$ annihilates the rhs if and only if $a_i\mid P$ for all $i$ if and only if $P$ is a multiple of $Q=\mathrm{lcm}(a_1,...,a_r)$. On the other hand, $(2,x)$ is the annihilator of $R/(2,x)$. But we then get that $(2,x)$ is a principal ideal of $R$, which is a contradiction.